# Magic-Zoom interfering with Fotorama?

Tags: jquery, zen-cart, fotorama, magiczoom

I've got Zen Cart 1.53, with Magic-Zoom, and tried adding a Fotorama image display with automatic thumbnails.  Magic-zoom seems to be auto zooming the thumbnails like it does on normal product thumbnails. This is simply an image slider on the main page and I don't want those images zoomed, as it interferes with the ability to use them as image nav-buttons in the slider.  Is there a way to inhibit the zooming?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a conflict between the two scripts that will be easy to resolve. It may be due to the name of the thumbnail style. However, it's not possible to identify the exact cause of the issue based upon the details you've given.

Please submit the URL of your page or send a login to the support team at Magic Toolbox https://www.magictoolbox.com/contact/ and they will identify the cause of the conflict and how to resolve it.

Or try the [Magic Zoom Plus API & callbacks](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/#api) for advanced control of how zooms behave on your page. The 11 API methods and 6 callbacks include:

```
MagicZoom.start(node)
MagicZoom.stop(node)
MagicZoom.refresh(node)
```

Comment: The site is http://www.woodyssportinggoods.com.  I didn't see it happening in Firefox, but Chrome instantly pops up max size images.   I was hoping that there was something built in to magic-zoom, like a stop() function that would have made it easy.